# Wcf endpoint customization for simplified configuration

Tags: .net, wcf, simplify, wcf-endpoint, wcf-configuration

I have a good amount of service contracts being implemented by the same class exposed over IIS, using simplified configuration (that is, no explicit `<service>` nodes in the config file).

This works fine and saves us a lot of trouble, because we have some logic on our clients to automatically build the endpoints pointing to the same url.

Now, I would like to customize one of the contracts on both the client and server, since it's behavior is quite different from the rest. I would like to use Streaming transport for this special contract class because it both returns and get's `Stream` instances.

As soon as I try to add a `<service>` node on the server, pointing to the shared implementation class and using this special contract interface, the whole auto configuration for the other services is lost, and I'm left with a single service exposed. I think this has to do with the fact that I'm using a single implementation class, and as soon as Wcf detects that there is a service with that class name in the config, it stops autogenerating the endpoints for the other contracts.

Is there a way to make this work, still sharing the same class and maintaining the simplified configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating your own service factory and overriding parts of the activation process.

Assume you have two service contracts like this.

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService2
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Foobar();
}
```

Assume these are implemented in a single class like this.

```
public class Service1 : IService1, IService2
{
    public string GetData(int value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
    public string Foobar()
    {
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to change the endpoint for just the second service contract, then in your .svc file, add the Factory property to point a custom service factory implementation.

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Factory="SimpleWCF2.MyServiceFactory" Service="SimpleWCF2.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>
```

Next, create a custom service factory that instantiates a custom service host.  In the custom service host, override the ApplyConfiguration and remove the default endpoint for contract 2 and replace it with a custom endpoint configuration.  For example, here I'm replacing the default "basicHttpBinding" with the "WsHttpBinding" only for contract 2.  You can of course configure the binding however you need (you mentioned streaming) - this is just an example.

```
public class MyServiceFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        return new MyServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
    }
}

public class MyServiceHost : ServiceHost
{
    public MyServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses) :
        base (serviceType, baseAddresses)
    { }

    protected override void ApplyConfiguration()
    {
        base.ApplyConfiguration();

        AddDefaultEndpoints();

        // Remove the default endpoint for IService2
        var defaultEp = this.Description.Endpoints.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Contract.ContractType == typeof(IService2));
        this.Description.Endpoints.Remove(defaultEp);

        // Add a new custom endpoint for IService2
        this.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService2), new WSHttpBinding(), "test");
    }
}
```

That's it. No change needed to your simplified configuration.

Now, your client will discover the second contract through the new service endpoint.  For example, here's the WCF Test Client from my sample.

[image]

Comment: That does makes sense to me, as I'm aware of how the factory system works. I'm worried about this not being scalable though... there should be a way to configure things through the normal `<services>` node but keep the default endpoint autogeneration intact. For instance, what if I find out that 5 of 50 services need special customization? This will become a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Well, my first response (which I replaced with this one), talked about that.  Maybe I should have left it.  :)  Anyway, you will basically have to separate out the unique service contracts into their own service (.svc).  This will allow the default configuration to still work for all your other services and let you explicitly define the configuration for the unique services.  The problem though (if you're cool with it) is that you will now have more than one entry point of activation.  For example, ~/defaultservice.svc for most service contracts, ~/uniqueservice1.svc for another.

Comment: The fact that there is a single entry point is exactly why I opted to implement every service on the same class. I have yet to answer it, but this is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016659/simplified-wcf-configuration-on-server-and-client) question I asked. I would like to avoid as much as possible having to manage multiple Urls as this new approach is much simpler to us. Considering that, is there an alternative?